# C# Convert Data Table value

Tags: c#, datatable

I read a csv file into DataTable, at some point I wanted to convert some columns from string to double to do some groupBy, etc. operation.

Here below a sample example which illustrated the problem. Is there any way to generate a new table (dt) from the previous one(table) by changing columns data to do some additional operations.

PS: I know that it has to be done from the begining using a the right data type.

```
    private void BtnApply_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataTable table = new DataTable();
        table.Columns.Add("RevenueI", typeof(string));
        table.Columns.Add("RevenueII", typeof(string));
        table.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));
        table.Columns.Add("Bonus", typeof(string));

        // Here we add five DataRows.
        table.Rows.Add("180.50", "45000.45", "David", "4700");
        table.Rows.Add("50.24", "22000.32", "Susane", "3500");
        table.Rows.Add("10.78", "41000.12", "Adam", "2800");
        table.Rows.Add("21.32", "33500.00", "Janet", "5400");
        table.Rows.Add("100.89", "52000.32", "Melanie", "2300");
        table.Rows.Add("25.23", "48978.00", "David", "3600");

        var dt = table.AsEnumerable()
          .GroupBy(r => r.Field<string>("Name"))
          .Select(g =>
          {
              var row = table.NewRow();

              row["Name"] = g.Key;
              row["RevenueI"] = g.Sum(r => r.Field<double>("RevenueI"));
              row["RevenueI"] = g.Sum(r => r.Field<double>("RevenueII"));
              row["Bonus"] = g.Sum(r => r.Field<double>("Bonus"));

              return row;
          }).CopyToDataTable();

        dtGrid.DataSource = dt;
```

Comment: Seems like you ought to do the conversion as you read in the CSV data.  There are tools which will do just that for you: CSVHelper, for instance, will read and parse the data into a typed collection ready to use as a datasource

Comment: Yes thanks I know, my question is to know is there any option to do it afterwards.